# Cloud functions' storage event has metadata from another event

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a node 10 cloud function triggered by a GCS event.

This cloud function need to access `data.metadata` property in order to track the file for our custom monitoring solution.

Users can trigger the download of a file, therefore sometimes the same file is uploaded multiple times to our bucket in a very short interval (~0.01s).

In this case, it happens that we receive in the cloud function event the metadata of another event, so we are losing track of an execution.

Do you think it is possible that, because of the short delay between the two messages, one of the message get the metadata of the other?

Answer (score 0):

Your case is hard to reproduce for providing you a solution. I recommend to check your code (again), even to share it if you want a community look, to understand why the files are upload twice.

So, I would like to say you that is impossible that a bug exists. Events are a very used and if this kind of errors exists it should be solved for long time.

**BUT** it's software development and bugs can occur. You can open a case here, on the public tracker if you want a Google look: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Comment: My issue is not that I upload a file twice but that, when I upload twice a file twice 
in one-tenth of a second my cloud function get the same metadata while it should get different metadata for each upload.

Comment: Could you let us know how is the Function Triggered? (Finalize/create, delete, archive,  metadata update)

Do you get exactly the same metadata? Or is it specific to just one field(s)?

When you're uploading a file twice, do you mean the same file?